# Set glyphText of MKMarkerAnnotationView for MKClusterAnnotation

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios11, mkannotationview

I have a class MapItem which implements MKAnnotation protocol. I am using MKMarkerAnnotationView for displaying Annotations on map.

According to Documentation,
glyphText property of MKMarkerAnnotationView when set to nil, it produces pin image on the marker.

When Clustering the annotation, **I want the same pin image on the marker.** But system by default sets this to the number of annotations clustered within this cluster.

I even tried setting this property to nil, but has no effect.

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let item = annotation as? MapItem {
        let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "mapItem") as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
            ?? MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "mapItem")

        annotationView.annotation = item
        annotationView.glyphText = nil
        annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = "mapItemClustered"

        return annotationView
    } else if let cluster = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation {
        let clusterView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "clusterView") as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
            ?? MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "clusterView")

        clusterView.annotation = cluster
        clusterView.glyphText = nil

        return clusterView
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell MKMarkerAnnotationView is severely broken when clustering.  There doesn't seem to be any way to change the glyphImage or glyphText.  When using a plain old MKAnnotationView you can set a custom image, but the markers cannot be customized.  Has anybody found a work around?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
class POIMarkerClusterView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            update(newValue: newValue)
        }
    }

    private func update(newValue: MKAnnotation?) {
        if let cluster = newValue as? MKClusterAnnotation {

            self.image = POIClusterImage(poiStatistics: poiStatistics, count: count)

            // MKMarkerAnnotationView's default rendering usually hides our own image.
            // so we make it invisible:
            self.glyphText = ""
            self.glyphTintColor = UIColor.clear
            self.markerTintColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }

}
```

This means you can set an arbitrary image that is rendered as the annotation view. I create the image dynamically, but you can just borrow the image from the `MKMarkerAnnotationView` and set it here, so it looks like the pin that you want.

The main trick is to use `UIColor.clear` to hide what you don't want to see.